# GCC Cortex-M4 -mfpu=vfpv4 vs. -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, cortex-m

I'm using a Freescale K22 (Cortex-M4F) with Kinetis Design Studio, which includes a GNU toolchain. I'm trying to use a binary-only library provided by Invensense, and they compiled it with GCC for use on a the Cortex-M4F using the compiler's CPU options "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv4"

The Freescale toolchain defaults to "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16". When I try to link my program with the vendor binary-only library, I get link errors like:

c:/freescale/kds_1.1.1/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: error: ./startup/startup.o uses VFP register arguments, 22F_eval_spi_to_invensense_CHECKED_IN.elf does not
c:/freescale/kds_1.1.1/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: failed to merge target specific data of file ./startup/startup.o

I can rebuild the Kinetis platform library for -mfpu=vfpv4, but I still get the link errors, presumably because other Kinetis libraries are compiled with 
"-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16".

Since both are intended for the Cortex-M4 with FPU, is there any actual difference between GCC generated code for vpfv4 and fpv4-sp-d16?  Are they actually incompatible, or is the linker just overly pedantic?

Comment: Using "vfpv4" seems just plain wrong - if the compiler really thinks it can use any double-precision operations or registers 16-31 that "full" VFPv4 implies, it's going to give you code that won't work. I don't know if there's some other magic involved, though (e.g. cross-checking the -mcpu option)

Comment: I agree, but I don't have any choice on vfpv4; it's what Invensense used when they compiled it for the Cortex-M4F, in their case, an STM32F4. I think they wrote all the code using float rather than double, so it shouldn't actually contain any double-precision instructions. Since the code is known to work on a Cortex-M4F, I'm going to try writing a script to change the Tag_FP_arch value from 5 (vfpv4) to 6 (fpv4-sp-d16) in the .ARM.attributes section of each .o in the vendor library.

Comment: Complain to the vendor and ask for them to fix the library. Any M4F is only compatible to `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16` - it looks like they have not tested their stuff properly.

Comment: I doubt they'll fix it. They have it tested and working on STM32F4, so I don't think they'll believe that it's a problem. The .ARM.attributes sections in the vendor library don't actually contain a Tag_FP_arch. I've used objcopy to remove the .ARM.attributes sections, which allows the code to link, but I haven't yet been able to verify that it works correctly.